# Is the use of API4 already recommended?

Tags: api, drupal-9, apiv4

I am currently working on a custom module for CiviCRM (5.48) and Drupal 9 (9.3.9)

I opted to use API4 but I notice that some things are missing compared to API3:

- Contribution -> completetransaction
- MembershipPayment
- ParticipantPayment

Are these done in a different way or has this not been developed yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2486 but I believe all of those things are deprecated anyway (or on the way to being deprecated) and the idea is to use Order and Payment: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/financial/orderAPI/

Comment: The description of this order API seems very promising to me, is it available via api4 it doesn't seem to appear in the list?

Comment: It doesn't look like Order and Payment are in api4 yet, but if you use the v3 version then it should be easy to switch to the v4 version when it's ready. Probably.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clear answer!